# Parameter SQL Insert into Statement SSIS Package

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that has an Execute SQL Task where I have a INSERT Statement that inserts log data to this ssis tracking table in smss that tracks the time of execution. 
Everytime I try to execute the task I get this error: ***[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "INSERT INTO dbo.SSIS_Logging_Details
(Execution_In..." failed with the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@ExecGUID".". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.***

1.This is the Statement I have in the SQLStatement field in the Execute SQL task:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SSIS_Logging_Details
          (Execution_Instance_GUID, Package_Name, Execution_Date)
          VALUES (@ExecGUID, @PackageName, GetDate())
```

2.I have the these parameters in the Parameter Mapping tab of the Execute SQL task:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiKvJ.png)

3.For the SQL table in smss:tableSSIS_Logging-Details here are the fields:

Execution_Instance_GUID nchar(100)  NULL

Package_Name                    nchar(100)  NULL

Execution_Date                  datetime        NULL

4.And for the 'Configure SSIS Logs: Package' I have the package in there with the provider type being SSIS Log Provider for SQL Server (but it keeps switching to SQL Server Profiler for some reason whenever I open it..)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU35S.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't use the variable names in the query in an execute sql task.   You replace them with question mark placeholders, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SSIS_Logging_Details
          (Execution_Instance_GUID, Package_Name, Execution_Date)
          VALUES (?, ?, GetDate())
```

In your parameter mapping, instead of parameter names, use their position starting with 0 for the first parameter.  So replace `@ExecGUID` with `0` and replace `@PackageName` with `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write it in this way:

```
DECLARE @ExecGUID NCHAR(100)
DECLARE @PackageName NCHAR(100)

SET @ExecGUID = ?
SET @PackageName = ?

INSERT INTO dbo.SSIS_Logging_Details
   (Execution_Instance_GUID, Package_Name, Execution_Date)
VALUES (@ExecGUID, @PackageName, GetDate())
```

I use this format, because I find it easier to test in Management Studio. Rather than looking for the `?`, this will keep all your assignments in one spot, especially if you have a large number of lines in an execute sql task.

You would still need to change the parameter mapping as [@Tab Alleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507566/tab-alleman) mentions in his answer.